# Retrieving a value through an iframe (C# ASPX)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an outer shell aspx page that displays an iframe and a button. When the button is pressed, I want the outer page to retrieve a value from within the iframe. How can I accomplish this?

The reason for this is that I want to compile a big list of user inputs, but break the inputs up over several pages. This is what I have currently: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLyIU.jpg I plan to change the iframe src and pass values between the sources without opening additional iframes.

The reason for such a setup is that the outer shell page will actually be called through an iframe on an apache server, to my windows server.

A simple answer, a point in the right direction, or an alternate approach would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why an iframe? You could use jQuery's .load to asynchronously load pages into a div and then hide/show them on demand.  You could even show them as a dialog.

Comment: I was trying to avoid javascript, but I will keep .load in mind if I can't get this to work. getElementById can grab values within an iframe, I was hopeful the .net framework held a similar functionality.

Comment: If Apache is on a different domain you're going to have trouble loading asynchronously without JSONP, which you may or may not want to use. You could make an asynchronous call to a proxy handler on your server to retrieve the Apache page though. Slower, but it gets around the problem nicely and removes the clumsy iframe.

Comment: Yes, my apache server is separate, but soon I am going to merge it onto the windows server so the aspx pages will be on the same domain (and under my private ssl). My only other idea is to not use iframes at all, instead just link between aspx pages while holding the data in Session. This isn't optimal either for a couple reasons, but it may have to do.

Comment: Ah, a quick test showed that Session persists through iframes. I should have tried that earlier. Now the button will read all Session variables, validate them, and then change the iframe src to the second page. After getting more values the shell page will parse them and store them securely. Thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fairly hard to pass variables directly what you could do is to place information in a Session in the "inner" page and retrieve it on the "outer" page upon a button click.

For an example if you upload a file do that on the Iframed page place the filename in the Session and save that upon the save Click.

Place in Session

```
Session["Variable"] = "content";
```

Fetch Sesion

```
string vriable = (string)Session["Variable"];
```